# $x_{n+1} = x^2_n - x_n + 1, x_1 = a > 1,$ find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}$, where $x_{n+1} = x^2_n - x_n + 1, x_1 = a > 1$. It's easy to see that $$\frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{x_n - 1}{x_{n + 1} - 1},$$
but I don't know what to do next. I've shown that $x_n$ diverges, but wasn't able to find the exact sum of $\frac{1}{x_n}$.

Comment: Three questions in just one hour?

Comment: If you have proved convergence of $\sum \frac 1  {x_n}$ then you must include that in your question.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}-1} =\frac{1}{(x_{n}-1)x_n} = \frac{1}{x_{n}-1} +\frac{1}{x_n}   $$ $$\implies \frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{x_{n+1}-1} - \frac{1}{x_{n}-1} $$

Comment: @NN2 - Sign error: $\;\dfrac{1}{(x_n-1)x_n}=\dfrac{1}{x_n-1}-\dfrac{1}{x_n}$.

Comment: @gpassante yes, but the idea remains correct and it suffices to use the telescopic technique. Any comment after 5minutes cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\forall n\in\mathbb N: x_{n+1}>x_n>1$

Proof:
$$\begin{equation}x_{n+1}-x_n=(x_n-1)^2>0 \\ x_{n+1}=x_n^2-x_n+1>1, \text{ because }x_n(x_n-1)>0\end{equation}$$

2. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (x_n-1)=+\infty$

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_n-1)=A \in (0,+\infty)$, then:
$$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n(x_n-1)=(A+1)A, \text{so } A=0$$
contradiction, then $A=+\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{x_n-1}=0$

3. Telescopic sum:
   $$\begin{equation}x_{n+1}=x_n^2-x_n+1 \\ \frac1{x_{n+1}-1}=\frac1{x_n(x_n-1)}=\frac1{x_n-1}-\frac1{x_n} \\ \frac1{x_n}=\frac1{x_n-1}-\frac1{x_{n+1}-1} \\ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{x_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{x_k-1}-\frac1{x_{k+1}-1}\right)=\frac1{x_1-1}-\frac1{x_{n}-1} \\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{x_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{x_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{x_1-1}-\frac1{x_n-1}\right)=\frac1{x_1-1}\end{equation}$$

**Answer:** $\dfrac1{x_1-1}$.